# Suppress PHP warnings for expected Oracle exceptions

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, suppress-warnings, oracle-call-interface

I have a PHP function that calls a PL/SQL package that can throw a number of known exceptions (i.e. user exceptions) that I can catch in PHP and act on. The problem is, despite catching the exception in PHP I get a warning in the PHP log file with a stack trace from the PL/SQL exception:

```
PHP Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-20001: Something isn't valid
ORA-234565: at "MY.PACKAGE", line 234
ORA-923485: at "MY.PACKAGE", line 123
```

How can I suppress these OCI warnings? I don't want to suppress all warnings as they can be helpful for other issues, but when it's an expected error from my PL/SQL I don't want it filling up my log file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only need to suppress the warning on `oci_execute()`, prepend it with `@`

```
@oci_execute()
```

Using that kind of runtime error suppression is often not recommended since it covers up problems in the application, but you've handled the problem in the code by catching the exception already and understand the consequence of suppressing the warnings.

[PHP docs on the `@` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)...

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Used @ for suppressing warning about XML when using XMLDocument - didn't think to use it for this.